# Transfer 100Gb photos from iPhone to Mac without Photos / Image Capture

Tags: iphone, photos, data-transfer

I have about 100Gb of photos accrued on my iPhone 6S and would like a workable solution to transfer a (large) selection of them directly to my Mac, preferably via USB.

- my iPhone does not appear in the Finder (despite what some older Google search results seem to suggest)
- I don't want to use the Photos app because I want the actual photos as files (JPG etc) not stuck in some proprietary archive format
- I can't use the ImageCapture app because it fails on such a large data set. It literally cannot handle the size of my library
- I don't want to use iTunes because I'm not looking to backup the whole things in one go.
- It seems that the only 3rd party apps available on the App Store do it via WiFi, not USB.
- Obviously I'm not emailing them to myself or using AirDrop because I'll still be here next year at that rate

What is going on here? Any other options?

Comment: Sorry to burst your bubble but photos.app stores the files in the same format they come off the phone. You can open the photoslibrary package and get the originals but the naming scheme is annoyingly non-helpful, so you **can** just move them out of the package file and delete the .photoslibrary file. You *could* export the files and just choose original format and you will retain the names they (may) already have but that would (temporarily at least) duplicate all the files along with all the space that would take up.

Comment: Why not use Image Capture in sections. Import a quarter, or just 10% to start with & see how it goes. I regularly use it to import large quantities [though maybe not 100GB] with no issues.

Comment: Note, your iPhone won't appear in Finder if you're running on macOS Mojave or earlier. It will only appear in Finder in Catalina and above since they removed the iTunes app in Catalina.

Comment: Every time I have to download photos from my iPhone it's such a pain. I don't use Photos, because it doesn't save photos in a folder but in its library. Image Capture crashes all the time.